# Using if and else

Tags: ruby

This line of code prints your account balance if the conditions are met:

```
p account.balance if num_account == account.num_account && agencia == account.agencia
```

I want to have `else` when these conditions are not met without repeating everything. Could you help me with this code?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
p num_account == account.num_account && agencia == account.agencia ? account.balance : something_else
```

Comment: Putting an else clause to do something *different* is not a Good practice for a one-line conditional. its' difficult to read which means it's easy to make mistakes or make your code hard to untangle (which makes it a a maintenance nightmare). Most ruby devs strongly prefer to put if/else structures as multi-line conditionals instead.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (num_account == account.num_account) && (agencia == account.agencia)
  p account.balance
else
  # here you go
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def valid_account?(account_number, agency)
  account_number == account.num_account && agency == account.agencia
end

account_balance = if valid_account?(num_account, agencia)
  account.balance
else
  # here you go
end
puts account_balance # or whatever it is you want to do with that.
```

Your line of code not only prints the account balance, it also represents it in human readable form.  This means that if it is represented as a string, you will get quotes, if it is returned as an array, you will get square brackets.  The `p` method is not a replacement or shortened substitute for `puts`.  It behaves differently.

You may want to refactor the conditional statement out of the if statement and make that longer code be represented by something like valid? and potentially provide arguments.  Better yet, have an object created that represents the account that is being queried.

It may look like this:

```
def account=(account_number, agency)
  @account_number, @agency = account_number, agency
end

def account_number
  @account_number
end

def agency
  @agency
end

def valid_account?
  account_number == account.num_account && agency == account.agencia
end
```

Then you may be able to do:

```
puts(valid_account? ? account.balance : "Something else")
```

Notice how simple valid_account becomes?  And you don't need the parenthesis (even in the conditional statement, due to precedence of `&&` compared to `==`.

The accessors, or getters, can be created by doing:

```
attr_reader :account_number, :agency
```

And then you can delete 6 lines of code above where `agency` and `account_number` methods are defined, leaving just the `account=` method and the `valid_account?` methods.

I am not sure if this was the best place to ask this question, as it seems like [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for this.  As this is feeling like a code review.

And no code has been tested, just giving descriptions.  If it runs for you, then that is a plus.  Also some names may have been changed from non-English to English, though I tried to be careful not to break the functionality.